# Alter the column of dataframe by matching other column with a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda, data-science

I have a situation :

```
postStr = """{
                     "zoneId":"0",
                     "id":["a","b","c","d","f","g"],
                     "currencycode":["USD"],

                }"""


postData = json.loads(postStr, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

And i have a dataframe:

```
df = {
'id':['a','b','c','d','f','g','h','i','j','k'],
'B':['c','d','e','d','d','c','s','e','s','q'],
'S':['f','g','h','j','e','j','t','r','p','p']
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

now i want a data frme such that if the id is in the dictionary then B corresponding column becomes XX

Output:

```
    df = {
'id':['a','b','c','d','f','g','h','i','j','k'],
'B' :['XX','XX','XX','XX','XX','c','s','e','s','q'],
'S' :['f','g','h','j','e','j','t','r','p','p']
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1.loc[df1['id'].isin(postData['id']), 'id'] = 'XX'
print (df1)
   id  B  S
0  XX  c  f
1  XX  d  g
2  XX  e  h
3  XX  d  j
4  XX  d  e
5  XX  c  j
6   h  s  t
7   i  e  r
8   j  s  p
9   k  q  p
```

If want more dynamic solution - use [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) for columns names in DataFrame and in dictionary and set values in loop:

```
postStr = """{
                     "S":["f","h"],
                     "id":["a","b","c","d","f","g"],
                     "currencycode":["USD"]

                }"""

postData = json.loads(postStr, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
print (postData)
OrderedDict([('S', ['f', 'h']), 
             ('id', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']), 
             ('currencycode', ['USD'])])

df = {
'id':['a','b','c','d','f','g','h','i','j','k'],
'B':['c','d','e','d','d','c','s','e','s','q'],
'S':['f','g','h','j','e','j','t','r','p','p']
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)

for col in df1.columns.intersection(postData.keys()):
    df1.loc[df1[col].isin(postData[col]), col] = 'XX'
print (df1)
   id  B   S
0  XX  c  XX
1  XX  d   g
2  XX  e  XX
3  XX  d   j
4  XX  d   e
5  XX  c   j
6   h  s   t
7   i  e   r
8   j  s   p
9   k  q   p
```

Comment: i did this but got:TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: self.resp_df.loc[self.resp_df['id'].isin(post_req['id']), 'returnType'] = 'CTR'

Comment: @ayushgupta - How working cast to list like `self.resp_df.loc[self.resp_df['id'].isin(list(post_req['id'])), 'returnType'] = 'CTR'` ?

Comment: self.resp_df.loc[self.resp_df['id'].isin(list(post_req['id'])), 'returnType'] = 'CTR'
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @ayushgupta - What is `print (type(postData['id']))` ?

Comment: @ayushgupta - I think `postData` not return `OrderedDict`, but string, so it failed.

Comment: i am sorry , i skiped one line  postData = json.dumps(postData) after this i have to do that

Comment: is there any solution if i want to go with the string format . I cant change postData = json.dumps(postData) what should i do next